# Angular router redirecting to random link on google is there any way to prevent the same?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular6, angular4-router

I have used # HashStrategy in my application when i put "prefix/#"  it is getting redirect to Google link

Router config file

{

```
      const mbRoutes: Routes = [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'Login',
             pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {path: 'Search-Contract' , component: SearchContractComponent},
          {path: 'Login' , component: LoginComponent},
          {path: 'Home' , component: HomeComponent, children: [
            { path: 'ContractDetails' , component: ContractMainPageComponent},
            {
              path: '',
              pathMatch: 'full',
              redirectTo: 'ContractDetails'
          }
          ]},
          {
            path: '**',
            redirectTo: '/Login'
          }
        ];
        export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(mbRoutes, { useHash: true });

}
```

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, Try to change "redirectTo: '/Login'" to "redirectTo: 'Login'" (removed '/').

Comment: @ArunKumarSaini I have tried that too but no luck